# How to set the file extension for C# generating T4 (runtime ) templates in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, t4

I have a T4 template that starts as

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".Generated.cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
```

but the generated name does not change in the solution explorer even though i have set the output directive

```
<#@ output extension=".Generated.cs" #>
```

the listing for the template and it's generated file in the explorer is

[image: solution explorer]

I want the generated file to be

```
ExportForNcGeneration.Generated.cs
```

so that I can tell Resharper to ignore all `.Generated.cs` files

Comment: Are you sure your'e using the T4 for `Text Template` (using `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` as Custom Tool) and not T4 for `Runtime Text Template` (using `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor` Custom Tool)?

Comment: Sorry yes it is T4 for runtime. I think it's not possible to customize the name of the output file in this case :(

Answer (score 2):

The simplistic approach: Name your template ExportForNcGeneration.Generated.tt

Slightly more tricky: Modify the .csproj file manually.

1. Open the .csproj file as a text
2. Search for ExportForNcGeneration.cs.
3. You should find two xml nodes in the .csproj that contains the name.
4. Change the name to ExportForNcGeneration.Generated.cs.
5. Reload the project
6. Regenerate the file, it should now have the correct name

The problem with this approach is that if you change the name of the .tt file in VS it will revert the name of the generated.

Comment: You can't name the template as you suggest as it will try to generate a class name ''ExportForNcGeneration.Generated.tt'' and crash the compiler :)